# How I can print specific cols and row from 2d array using for loop in python and also want to change gray image to RGB

Tags: python

I make 2d array ,now I want to print only specific rows and cols using for loop in python .plz help what I should do

```
type from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rows, cols = (120, 120)
arr = [[0]*cols]*rows
arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
#for i in range(10, 16):
 #   print(i)

#for alif
arr[10][110]=255;arr[11][110]=140;arr[12][110]=140;arr[13][110]=140;arr[14][110]=140;arr[15][110]=140
#for pay

arr[10][80]=255;arr[11][80]=255;arr[12][80]=255;arr[13][80]=255;arr[14][80]=255;arr[15][80]=255;arr[15][79]=255;arr[15][78]=255
arr[15][77]=255;arr[15][76]=255;arr[15][75]=255;arr[15][74]=255;arr[15][73]=255;arr[15][72]=255;arr[15][71]=255;arr[19][75]=255
arr[19][73]=255;arr[21][74]=255;arr[10][70]=255;arr[11][70]=255;arr[12][70]=255;arr[13][70]=255;arr[14][70]=255;arr[15][70]=255

# Set the figure size
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [6.00, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

# Random data points
data = np.random.rand(5, 5)
#data[0][4] = 255
# Plot the data using imshow with gray colormap
plt.imshow(data, cmap='gray')
plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray')
# Display the plot
  

plt.show()
```

I want to print only for  alif values on gray image using for loop
plz help what should I do

Comment: There are many, many, different layouts for printing this out, please edit your question to show *exactly* what you want the print output to be.

Comment: Why do you initialise the array Twice?

Comment: use the `print` function

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you want to read specific values from the nested list or also to write. Anyway, you can *manually* create a list with for example `tuple` representing the coordinates of the entry.

```
rows, cols = 4, 7
arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]

# read
list_of_indices = [
    (1, 5),
    (3, 2)
]
for i, j in list_of_indices:
    print(arr[i][j])


# write
list_of_indices_values = [
    ((10, 5), 10),
    ((3, 2), 140),
]

for (i, j), value in list_of_indices_values:
    arr[i][j] = value

print(*arr, sep='\n')
```

---

I think that the initialization in the form `arr = [[0]*cols]*rows` is "biased" in your case because each of its rows point to the same object in memory which means if modify an entry in one row then also the others rows will change because the are the same object in memory.

```
rows, cols = (2, 3)

# "biased" initialization
arr = [[0]*cols]*rows

# modify a single entry
arr[1][1] = 313
for row in arr:
  print(row, f"memory address {id(row)}")
#[0, 313, 0] memory address 140104314213248  # same addresses
#[0, 313, 0] memory address 140104314213248


# "right" initialization
arr =  [[0 for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]
arr[1][1] = 313
for row in arr:
  print(row, f"memory address {id(row)}")
#[0, 0, 0]   memory address 140313049731968  # different addresses!
#[0, 313, 0] memory address 140313050428928
```

So, use the comprehension approach to initialized nested lists.

---

EDITED

Step 1: update the "array", `arr`, with specific values

Replace this

```
#for alif
arr[10][110]=255;arr[11][110]=140;arr[12][110]=140;arr[13][110]=140;arr[14][110]=140;arr[15][110]=140
```

with

```
alif_index_value_pairs = [
    ((10, 110), 255), ((11, 110), 140), ((12, 110),140), # ...
]
for (i, j), v in alif_index_value_pairs:¨
    arr[i][j] = v
```

and

```
#for pay
arr[10][80]=255;arr[11][80]=255;arr[12][80]=255;arr[13][80]=255;arr[14][80]=255;arr[15][80]=255;arr[15][79]=255;arr[15][78]=255
arr[15][77]=255;arr[15][76]=255;arr[15][75]=255;arr[15][74]=255;arr[15][73]=255;arr[15][72]=255;arr[15][71]=255;arr[19][75]=255
arr[19][73]=255;arr[21][74]=255;arr[10][70]=255;arr[11][70]=255;arr[12][70]=255;arr[13][70]=255;arr[14][70]=255;arr[15][70]=255
```

with

```
forpay_index_value_pairs = [
    (10, 80), (11,80), (12,80), (13, 80), (14, 80), # ...
]
for (i, j), v in forpay_index_value_pairs:
    arr[i][j] = 255
```

Step 2: reading specific values, for ex those for *alif*

```
for (i, j), _ in alif_index_value_pairs:
    print(arr[i][j])
```

Comment: the initialization was already did by you with `arr`, right? the whole 2s list? in which form? linewise or termwise?

Comment: i want to print these some values through for loop

Comment: then  use the code right below the 1st comment, `# read` . You need to update the list of tuple, `list_of_indices `, with your actual values for the indices

Comment: the task is given me  to show these  some array elements by using only  for loop

Comment: I showed you how to do that: take all the values which are separated by a `;` in your code and write them in the form of `list_of_indices`. Your last edit didn't clarify much... try to make a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe what is your input and expected output.

Comment: i want to show like   arr [10][110]=255; arr [11][110]=255;by using for loop in which row start frm 10 to 16 and column is always 110

Comment: i want to show all indicies from alif to pay using for loop instead of  writing all indices

Comment: their are **not** uniquely identified... so you cannot do that in general. You may have a chance only **before** the initialization of the _forpay_ list. Here an example: `for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[0])):
        if arr[i][j] != 0:
            print(i, j)`